# How do I stop this div from fading using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner with jquery, so this will probably be easy for most of you. I pasted my code in jsFiddle so it's easy to understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zn6tM/

After clicking the second image (Yahoo), I want the `#textholder` div to fade in just like the Yahoo image faded in after clicking the Google image. Instead, it's fading it directly after Yahoo.

How can I click the Yahoo image, and then the `#textholder` div fades in after clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't handling the click event on the yahoo image. You were just running the fadeIn directly after the yahoo-fadeIn had finished.

Give this a try...

http://jsfiddle.net/K63nS/ -- sorry my first fiddle didn't save for some reason. This one should be good.

http://jsfiddle.net/K63nS/1/ - yahoo fades out before div fades in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I don't see any difference between what I posted and what you posted.

Comment: yeah. i noticed that. I just updated the answer with a new fiddle link.

Comment: That works! But how can Yahoo fade away before the `#textholder` div appears?

Comment: ya know, I almost did that from the beginning but then I read your question and just followed the instructions :) Added another fiddle. that should work for you.

Comment: I see what you did. I had something similar, but for some reason (it's late here hah) I added `find('.image2')`. Thanks for you help!